# Problems running tidync on windows - convert filtered nc object to dataframe

Tags: r, netcdf, ncdf4

I have a series of netCDF files which I am trying to convert to a dataframe after filtering the dimensions. This worked fine on my Mac, but I cannot get `hyper_tibble()` or `hyper_array()` to run on my Windows PC. There's no error, the function just doesn't complete and eventually causes R to crash. This should not be because of file size as I'm only expecting an output ~3000 rows (see filtered dimensions below). I'm not able to upload a data sample which was accessed from https://data.marine.copernicus.eu/product/NWSHELF_MULTIYEAR_PHY_004_009/services, but the data structure is as follows:

```
library(tdync)
nc <- tidync(url)
print(nc)

Data Source (1): cmems_mod_nws_phy-uv_my_7km-2D_PT1H-i ...

Grids (4) <dimension family> : <associated variables> 

[1]   D1,D0,D2 : vo, uo    **ACTIVE GRID** ( 28796229000  values per variable)
[2]   D0       : latitude
[3]   D1       : longitude
[4]   D2       : time

Dimensions 3 (all active): 
  
  dim   name      length         min          max start  count        dmin         dmax unlim coord_dim 
  <chr> <chr>      <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl> <int>  <int>       <dbl>        <dbl> <lgl> <lgl>     
1 D0    latitude     375        40.1         65.0     1    375        40.1         65.0 FALSE TRUE      
2 D1    longitude    297       -19.9         13.0     1    297       -19.9         13.0 FALSE TRUE      
3 D2    time      258552 725850000   1656633600       1 258552 725850000   1656633600   FALSE TRUE
```

I then subset the data using:

```
## SUBSET .NC DATA
y <- -2.3
x <- 56.5

nc_sub <- nc %>%
  hyper_filter(latitude = index == which.min(abs(latitude - y)), # closest lat/lon in nc to my x and y
  longitude = index == which.min(abs(longitude - x)),
  time = dplyr::between(time, "2021-11-22 09:59:00 UTC", "2022-03-15 13:59:00 UTC"))

print(nc_sub)

Grids (4) <dimension family> : <associated variables> 

[1]   D1,D0,D2 : vo, uo    **ACTIVE GRID** ( 28796229000  values per variable)
[2]   D0       : latitude
[3]   D1       : longitude
[4]   D2       : time

Dimensions 3 (all active): 
  
  dim   name      length         min          max  start count          dmin          dmax unlim coord_dim 
  <chr> <chr>      <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>  <int> <int>         <dbl>         <dbl> <lgl> <lgl>     
1 D0    latitude     375        40.1         65.0    248     1         56.5          56.5  FALSE TRUE      
2 D1    longitude    297       -19.9         13.0    159     1         -2.33         -2.33 FALSE TRUE      
3 D2    time      258552 725850000   1656633600   253258  2716 1637575200    1647349200    FALSE TRUE
```

Finally,
`nc_tib <- nc_sub %>% hyper_tibble()`; `nc_sub %>% hyper_array()`; `nc_sub %>% hyper_slice(select_var = "vo")` all just cause R to freeze. Is there another way to do this (possibly outside of tidync pacakge?) or to configure the packages when installing on Windows?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What do you mean by freeze? Is R running out of RAM? It sounds like nc_sub has not been created properly. If you convert that to a dataframe it will have 375x297x258552 rows. That will take up a lot of RAM. Check the code for how you created it

Comment: R doesn't appear to be running out of RAM either in the Memory display above the environment pane in RStudio or in Windows Task Manager. It just never completes the task and eventually R crashes. When I run the same code on a mac (including filtering nc_sub) I end up with a tibble that is 2716 rows (dims D0*D1*D2 = 1*1*2716). I believe the line `[1]  D1,D0,D2 : vo, uo **ACTIVE GRID** ( 28796229000  values per variable)` just displays the size of the original grid regardless, like how `length` in the Dimensions shows the original dimension length and `count` is the dim length after filtering.